# Possible binary numbers function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that does this: **returns all the binary numbers with N digits, and in sorted order. Each binary number is represented as a tuple. The result of calling AllBinary(N) is a tuple containing 2^N binary numbers.** Example:

```
AllBinary(2)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

I am trying to write the function using either a for or while loop. This is my code:

```
def AllBinary(N):
    c =[]
    for i in range(2**N):
```

I think I can solve it using an accumulation for loop by having the loop create the tuples of binary and then add them to the empty list c. But I am not sure how I am going to code the loop to get me those binary tuples.

Comment: There's a number of ways of getting the binary digits of an integer, but the ones that spring to mind are the `%` operator (applied repeatedly) and the `bin` builtin function.

Comment: Forgot to add: I would like no import statements in the function.

Comment: @SteveJessop, don't forget `>>` and `&`

Comment: @user2929403, are you trying to get people to do homework for you? The idea that you don't want any import statement in the function is insane otherwise ;-)

Comment: You could always move the import statements outside the function.

Answer (score 3):

```
def AllBinary(N):
    import itertools
    return itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=N)
```

Example:

```
>>> for t in AllBinary(3):
...    print t

(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add 2 more lines to what you have

```
>>> def AllBinary(N):
...     c =[]
...     for i in range(2**N):
...         c.append(tuple((i>>j)&1 for j in reversed(range(N))))
...     return c
... 
>>> AllBinary(3)
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

If you're not happy to use bitwise operators either (although it is less efficient)

```
>>> def AllBinary(N):
...     c =[]
...     for i in range(2**N):
...         c.append(tuple((i//2**j)%2 for j in reversed(range(N))))
...     return c
... 
>>> AllBinary(3)
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a power set.

There are plenty of copy-and-paste algorithms for these.

However, 2^n is a lot + Python's overhead (which is 12 bytes per int if I recall correctly), 32 digits will give you 4gb per byte, so 4*12 = 48gb of memory to store.

It would be trivial to see if a number is in this power set.

It would also be a good excuse to learn about generators and yielding, as finite power-sets are countable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def AllBinary(N):
    c =[]
    for i in xrange(2**N):
        c.append(tuple(bin(i)[2:].zfill(N)))
    return c
```

Explanation:

- `for i in xrange(2**N):` - note: use `xrange` instead of `range` here to be more efficient. Hopefully you already understand the math behind why we are iterating between 0 and 2^N.
- `bin(i)` - Convert `i` into binary representation. e.g. `5` will be `0b101`
- `bin(i)[2:]` - Throw away the first two characters that denote binary representation, which in this case is `0b`
- `bin(i)[2:].zfill(N)` - Now zero-pad the left-most zeros, because we want N digits
- `tuple(...)` - Convert this into a tuple
- `c.append(...)` - Add each such tuple into the `c` list
- `return c` - Either return this or print it, or do what is required by your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive implementation that uses no other functions as requested:

```
def all_bin(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [(0,), (1,)]
    return [(i, ) + b for i in (0, 1) for b in all_bin(n - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested for loops to solve this problem

```
def AllBinary(num):
    result, binary = [[]], (0, 1)
    for total in xrange(num):
        result = [i + [j] for i in result for j in binary]
    return result

print AllBinary(2)
print AllBinary(3)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

**Note:** It is same as using [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but we dont have to `import` anything.